# Binding textbox in ListView's header datatemplate to a filter property

Tags: wpf, listview, binding, listbox, datatemplate

I am creating a customized listview header that has the header text but also has a textbox that you can enter to filter the content of that column. My code currently looks like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="myHeaderTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontSize="14" Foreground="DarkBlue" Margin="20,4" Text="{Binding}" />
                <TextBox Text="" Margin="4,2" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

which is the definition for the header datatemplate containing the texbox; and the listview

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyData}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource myHeaderTemplate}"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Something}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource myHeaderTemplate}" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Something}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Address" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource myHeaderTemplate}" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Tube}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I want to be able to build up a filter statement that I can apply to the listview rows, but to do that I have to get the data from each filter textbox in the header template.

Can I somehow bind the textboxes in the headers to properties on my viewmodel? If not is there some other way to get the text?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to bind the header to a property like this:

```
<GridViewColumn 
    Header="{Binding LastNameFilter, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" 
    HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource myHeaderTemplate}"
    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Something}" />
```

The `RelativeSource` is needed to get to the `DataContext` of the `ListView` - you could also give it a name and use `ElementName` instead.

Now you can make a `HeaderFilter` class:

```
public class HeaderFilter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Filter { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously you would need to extend that class to hook into the event when `Filter` is changed to perform the filtering.

Put a property for each column header on the object which is the `DataContext` for your `ListView` (same object which provides `MyData` probably)

```
public class SomeClass
{
    ....
    public HeaderFilter LastNameFilter { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Brillant answer ChrisWue, thats just the ticket. Thanks very much for the great explanation!

Comment: ChrisWue I am trying what you suggested and I am having difficulty understanding the binding statement you used above, specifically

Header="{Binding LastNameFilter, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"

Comment: ChrisWue I am trying what you suggested and I am having difficulty understanding the binding statement you used above, specifically

Header="{Binding LastNameFilter, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"

   Is this statement getting the LastNameFilter property of the datacontext of the ListView or trying to get the LastNameFilter property of the ListView itself? Should it be Binding DataContext.LastNameFilter instead? Thanks!