# Binding Textbox in Datagrid Header Datatemplate to a Filter Property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datatemplate

I am creating a customized DataGrid Header that has the header text but also has a textbox that you can enter to filter the content of that column. I try to use strictly the mvvm pattern. My code currently looks like this:
This is the definition for the Header Datatemplate containing the Textblock and Texbox

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myHeaderTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Filter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

This is the usage of the Template inside the DataGrid

```
<FrameworkElement x:Name="dgProcesss" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ListProcess}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="{Binding DataContext.FirstNameFilter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Source={x:Reference dgProcesss}}"
            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource myHeaderTemplate}"
            Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And this is the filter for a column inside my ViewModel

```
    public HeaderFilter FirstNameFilter
    {
        get => this.firstNameFilter;
        set
        {
            firstNameFilter = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FirstNameFilter));
            //this is never called
        }
    }
```

the following code defines the FilterClass which determines what to filter

```
    public class HeaderFilter : ViewModelBase
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        private string filter;
        public string Filter
        {
            get => this.filter;
            set
            {
                filter = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Filter));
                //here code is reached
            }
        }
    }
```

The template works so far, but when I do perform key entries inside the filter textbox
only the Class setter (Headerfilter) gets called. The class instance (FirstName) setter is never called. Could somebody give me some adivce please.

I used code from a old example:
[Binding textbox in ListView's header datatemplate to a filter property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610190/binding-textbox-in-listviews-header-datatemplate-to-a-filter-property)
But this is not 100 percent crystal clear.

Thanks in advance.